# When generate android build in jenkins it gives me error?

Tags: android, jenkins, aapt2

I have successfully generated build from the android studio but when I am trying to generate build using `Jenkins` it gives an error. Please check log in below link.

https://pastebin.com/cwWMYdyx

Comment: please localize the error and show only relevant piece of log. Nobody wants to read that whole book.

Comment: you need to update your gradle wrapper https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Please include your relevant output here.

Comment: @duggu update gradle still same issue there